# How to build an infinite canvas and have ability to save and restore drawings on their original position?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am building an event website in React and I want to make a page where anyone could draw or paint on infinite canvas and it would get saved in database. So it would be like infinite canvas of toughts.

I would appreciate if someone could point me in right direction of making this.

I tried some canvas and drawing modules for react, but still, there is problem of how to save it and restore it on corect x,y position.

Similar site is https://www.anondraw.com/

Comment: by definition an `infinite canvas` requires `infinite resources` - so, perhaps you want to re-think the problem

Comment: Alright, a big canvas, big enough that 50 sentences could be written on it. Or 50 drawings.

Comment: To do this, you must first of all re-think about using React.